# C++ Iterating a huge std::multimap while handling many elements going MIA

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, iterator, multimap

I have a situation where `object`s will add events (a struct containing a function pointer to a function like `object::do_something`) to a "chain of events" (`std::multimap`) in their constructor. My interpreter reads the chain of events (sorted by depth) every time the game updates and executes each one sequentially. When an `object` is destroyed, it will remove all its events from the chain in its destructor automatically (to prevent possible leaks of events).

Because events are sorted by depth, it's possible that an object might register multiple events which are "next" to each other in the chain. When an object destroys itself, it unlinks all its events and immediately stops running its share of code (when something is destroyed, it can't do anything). I've cunningly produced a way of doing this; the particular function which deletes an object, `instance_destroy()` will throw an exception which my event interpreter can catch and continue along with the next event in the chain.

I've come to realize;

- Unpredictable amounts of events can be unlinked from the chain, and the current iterator is (likely) to be invalidated when an object destroys itself.
- Objects can destroy other objects in their lifetime, as well as themselves. I can't simply keep a copy of the next iterator that doesn't belong to the current object in case of destruction, as it could also be removed!

When control is passed back to the interpreter (say, via exception) and *heaps* of events have been removed, including possibly the current iterator, I have no way of knowing what to execute next. I can't start the map from the beginning -- that would cause undefined behaviour in the game; things would be executed twice. I also can't copy the map -- it's absolutely **HUGE** -- it would come at an enormous performance penalty. I can't redesign the way the system should work either, as it's not my protocol.

Consider the following data structure;

```
typedef std::multimap<real_t, event> events_by_depth_t;
```

How can I iterate it given my requirements above?

I'm using C++11.

Comment: Why not mark them invalid and then once you're done iterating remove them all at the same time.

Comment: That's actually a really good idea! I hadn't thought about it like that. It does have the disadvantage I have to iterate the huge multi map twice, though. That's not something that's ideal to do *every frame*. I would rather delete them as they are destroyed. It's a rare occurrence for things to delete things, and I don't want to pay the price when it's not happening.

Comment: Actually, extending upon that, I could have a structure which contains all the iterators that need to be removed. That way I can O(n) remove them all without iterating the multimap. I still have to mark them as invalid so they aren't executed.

Comment: @kvanberendonck You don't need to mark them as invalid when you have access to this structure during iteration: Just check if the iterator you are processing is in the set of to-be-removed iterators.

Comment: @DanielFrey that seems kind of inefficient unless there is a really *really* (faster than a comparison) data structure I can use for O(1) union checks. Suggestions?

Comment: @kvanberendonck I was thinking of `std::unordered_set` which has O(1) lookup.

Comment: Cheers, I'd have to write a fast hashing function though. That doesn't seem too hard.

Comment: `typedef std::multimap<real_t, std::weak_ptr<event>>` and have the "owning" events keep `std::shared_ptr`.  As you iterate, `.lock()`, if the `lock` fails remove the entry and advance.  Lifetime is managed by the `shared_ptr` that "owns" the `event` (which is not the `multimap`).  This does require that ownership be statically described by code data structure, which is a good idea, but might be hard to fix your project.  Alternatively, just stick a `bool` that says the event is invalid, and strip invalid events as you iterate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Yakk! I appreciate it, but I'm going with Ninja's suggestion. :)